# Javascript - Filter object containing arrays with value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem implementing filtering for nested data. I have this kind of data from API  :

```js
  const animals = {
    bugs: ['ant', 'cricket'],
    fish: ['shark', 'whale', 'tuna'],
    mammals: ['cow', 'horse', 'sheep'],
    birds: ['eagle', 'crow', 'parrot'],
    predators: ['tiger', 'lion']
  }
```

I have to filter them with this array :
`const data = ['shark', 'horse', 'cow', 'parrot']`

The result I want to achieve :

```
const filtered = {
    fish: ['shark'],
    mammals: ['cow', 'horse'],
    birds: ['parrot'],
}
```

I have tried :

```
filter.forEach((item) => {
      for (let key in animals) {
        let species = []
        if (animals[key].includes(item)) {
          filtered[key] = [...species, species]
        }
      }
    })
```

and the result :

```
const filtered = {
      fish: ['whale'],
      mammals: ['cow',],
      birds: ['parrot'],
    }
```

I still can't achieve the desired outcome, because the items inside array will not be added but replaced. I'm stuck here. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, What's your attempt and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rebuild the entries of the object.

```js
const
    animals = { bugs: ['ant', 'cricket'], fish: ['shark', 'whale', 'tuna'], mammals: ['cow', 'horse', 'sheep'], birds: ['eagle', 'crow', 'parrot'], predators: ['tiger', 'lion'] },
    data = ['shark', 'horse', 'cow', 'parrot'],
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(animals)
        .flatMap(([k, a]) => {
            a = a.filter(v => data.includes(v));
            return a.length
                ? [[k, a]]
                : []
        })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to loop your object then filter arrays of animals according to data.

```js
const animals = {  fish: ['shark', 'whale', 'tuna'],  mammals: ['cow', 'horse', 'sheep'],  birds: ['eagle', 'crow', 'parrot'],};
const data = ['shark', 'horse', 'cow', 'parrot'];

let filtered = {};
for (var a of Object.keys(animals)) {
  filtered[a] = animals[a].filter(value => data.includes(value));
}
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: wow. Thanks for the answer. It worked for my current question. My bad, I forgot to mention one thing. I updated it. The animals array contains more fields than the data. For example it has 8 fields where the data has only 3. Your answer is great but it will leave some object with empty arrays. How to return only fields that is not containing empty array ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` method:

```js
const fish = animals.fish.filter((animal) => animal === 'shark');
const mammals = animals.mammals.filter((animal) => animal === 'cow' || animal === 'horse');
const birds = animals.birds.filter((animal) => animal === 'parrot');

const filtered = {
  fish, // equals to fish: fish
  mammals, // equals to mammals: mammals
  birds, // equals to birds: birds
};
```

**Note that this is just an example. You can put your own checks in the callback functions but it should return a boolean.**

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the object and create a new one with the filtered data

```js
  const animals = {
    bugs: ['ant', 'cricket'],
    fish: ['shark', 'whale', 'tuna'],
    mammals: ['cow', 'horse', 'sheep'],
    birds: ['eagle', 'crow', 'parrot'],
    predators: ['tiger', 'lion']
  }

const data = ['shark', 'horse', 'cow', 'parrot']
const filtered = {};

for ( arr in animals) {
  filtered[arr] = animals[arr].filter ( x => data.includes(x))
}

console.log(filtered)
```

EDIT if you don't want empty arrays as part of the solution:

```js
const animals = {
    bugs: ['ant', 'cricket'],
    fish: ['shark', 'whale', 'tuna'],
    mammals: ['cow', 'horse', 'sheep'],
    birds: ['eagle', 'crow', 'parrot'],
    predators: ['tiger', 'lion']
  }

const data = ['shark', 'horse', 'cow', 'parrot']
const filtered = {};
let tmp = [];
for ( arr in animals) {
  tmp  = animals[arr].filter ( x => data.includes(x))
  if (tmp.length > 0) filtered[arr] = tmp
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is great and concise. Thanks!. But how to make the result just contains fields with non empty array values?

Comment: @FadhilRadh  I've edited the answer with a tmp val to let out the empty arrays